# Adding displayname at register stage with vue.js and firebase auth

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuex

Greetings dear stackoverflow users. I'm developing a project with vue js and firebase auth and now I'm trying to register, there are email and password parts, but I have difficulty in synchronizing the username state that I keep on my register page to the displayname in firebase auth during the registration process in the vuex store.

RegisterView.vue :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form @submit.prevent="register">
      <div>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="username" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="email" v-model="email" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" v-model="password" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        Zaten Üye misiniz ?
        <router-link to="/login">Giriş Yapın</router-link>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
  
  <script>
export default {
  name: 'register',
  data() {
    return {
      username: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async register() {
      try {
        await this.$store.dispatch("register", {
          username: this.username,
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
        });
        // redirect to home page
        this.$router.push("/");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
  },
};
  </script>
```

store/index.js :

```
    import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
  // my firebase config
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export const authGuard = (to, from, next) => {
  const currentUser = auth.currentUser;
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);

  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
    next('/login');
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

export default createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) || null,
      error: '',
    };
  },
  mutations: {
    setUser(state, payload) {
      state.user = payload;
    },
    setError(state, payload) {
      state.error = payload;
    },
    clearError(state) {
      state.error = '';
    },
    setUsername(state, username) {
      state.username = username;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async register({ commit, state }, payload) {
      try {
        const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, payload.email, payload.password);

        commit('setUser', user);
        commit('clearError');
      } catch (error) {
        commit('setError', error.message);
      }
    },

    async login({ commit }, payload) {
      try {
        const { user } = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, payload.email, payload.password);
        commit('setUser', user);
        console.log(user);
        console.log(user.displayName);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
        commit('clearError');
      } catch (error) {
        commit('setError', error.message);
      }
    },
    async logout({ commit }) {
      try {
        await signOut(auth)
        commit('setUser', null)
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
        commit('clearError')
        router.push('/login')
      } catch (error) {
        commit('setError', error.message)
      }
    },
    autoLogin({ commit }) {
      const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      if (user) {
        commit('setUser', user);
      }
    }
  }
});
```